# referring to initial quote in footnotes in brackets in LyX

Tags: biblatex, lyx, quoting, quotation

In my field, there are some special requirements for quoting which I'd like to implement in my LyX template. I'm working with biblatex.

Does anyone know how I could refer (automatically) to a long quote of a work in the following text, s. e.g. in FN 25 which refers to the long quote in FN 22 in brackets?
Ideally, I'd love to know how to implement this quoting feature in LyX, but I'd also try to work with TeX-code.

Thank you very much in advance!

[image]

Comment: Does it do what you want if you put a label in the footnote 22 and then reference it in footnote 25?

Comment: Thank you, that's a possible solution, although not idea in terms of practicability as well as the structure of the quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `verbose-note` style family (`verbose-note` and `verbose-inote`) has this feature.

You can use `verbose-note` with some small modifications to fit the desired style a bit better

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=verbose-note,
  citepages=separate,
]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  seenote = {wie Anm.\adddot},
}

\renewbibmacro*{footcite:note}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\printfield{label}}
    {\printnames{labelname}}%
  \setunit*{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
  \printfield[title]{labeltitle}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printtext[parens]{%
    \bibstring{seenote}\addnbspace
    \ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}%
    \iftoggle{cbx:pageref}
      {\ifsamepage{\the\value{instcount}}
                  {\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}
         {}
         {\addcomma\space\bibstring{page}\addnbspace
          \pageref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}}}
      {}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[Vgl.][12]{worman}
ipsum \autocite{nussbaum}
dolor \autocite[45]{worman}
sit \autocite[3]{geer}
amet\footnote{\Cite[78]{worman}.
  A longer footnote with some more text.}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Worman, Cast of Character (wie Anm. 1), S. 78. A longer footnote with some more text.]

---

Here's how you would go about getting this style in LyX.

Go to *Documents > Settings... > Bibliography*

- select "Biblatex" under *Style format* and "Author-year" under *variant*.
- Add `citepages=separate` to the  *Options* field.
- In *Biblatex citation style* select `verbose-note`.
- Click *Match* to get `verbose-note` also as *Biblatex bibliography style*.
- Make sure "Biber" is selected as *Processor* under *Bibliography Generation*.

The settings should look pretty much like this.

[image: Screenshot of the settings window with everything set as explained above.]

Then go to *LaTeX Preamble* and paste

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
    seenote = {wie Anm.\adddot},
  }%
  \renewbibmacro*{footcite:note}{%
    \ifnameundef{labelname}
      {\printfield{label}}
      {\printnames{labelname}}%
    \setunit*{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
    \printfield[title]{labeltitle}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \printtext[parens]{%
      \bibstring{seenote}\addnbspace
      \ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}%
      \iftoggle{cbx:pageref}
        {\ifsamepage{\the\value{instcount}}
                    {\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}
           {}
           {\addcomma\space\bibstring{page}\addnbspace
            \pageref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}}}
        {}}}%
}
```

into the preamble window.

Press "Apply".

Now you can insert your bibliography and citations as usual. For best results select `\autocite` when you insert citations.

Comment: Wow, thanks a million! It's exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much, moewe!